# CDF and PDF of $\sqrt X$ with uniform distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables

I would like to double check my approach to this problem:
Let $X$ be uniform $\sim [0,1]$. For the random variable $Y=\sqrt X$, find the PDF and CDF.
I got the CDF to be: $$
F_Y(x) = \begin{cases}0 ,& \text{if }\; x ≤ 0,\\
      x^2,& \text{if }\; 0 ≤ x≤ 1,\\
     1, &\text{if }\; x ≥ 1. \end{cases}$$
To find the PDF, differentiate the CDF, right? But I am a bit lost on how to do this. I have scoured my textbook for hours and would appreciate some sort of direction. Thank you!

Comment: It's a piecewise function. You differentiate each piece to get $f'(x)$ over that piece.

Comment: @Semiclassical So the PDF would be 2x? Also to clarify - the CDF is presented as piecewise but the PDF is not, right? Sorry if this is a really dumb question. I am just struggling to grasp the obvious and my teacher literally did not take us through any examples

Comment: For $0\leq x\leq 1$, yes. (Though to avoid ambiguity, I'd prefer to let $Y=\sqrt{X}$ and therefore $P(Y\leq y)=y^2\implies dP/dy = 2y$. It's the same function but emphasizes the transformation.)

Comment: @Semiclassical For the other parts, the PDF is just zero I believe? Would I need to specify that on the solution? Sorry for all the questions, just want to clarify how a solution to this type of question should be presented.

Answer (score 2):

You just differentiate the CDF; since it is a piece-wise function, you differentiate it separately at each interval. The result will be

$$
f_Y(x)=\frac{d}{dx} F_Y(x)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } x<0;\\
2x &\text{if } 0\le x\le 1;\\
0 &\text{if } x>1
\end{cases}
=\begin{cases}
2x &\text{if } 0\le x\le 1;\\
0 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you for verifying, this is what I thought!